# Power BI - Limit the Constant Line of the Bar Graph to the only Bar of the Graph (and not the whole Element)

Tags: powerbi

I have a bar graph like this,

[image]

What I am trying to do is actually add a **"Solid Red Constant Line"** to represent the **"Target"** number on the Bar.

However, I want it to only **limit to the Bar of the Graph** and not cover the whole area of the element. I can't seem to find any settings that can help me with this.

I also tried to reduce the size of the Bar Graph (to only limit the size to the Bar of the Graph, but that shrinks the bar itself and doesn't remove the inner padding between the bar graph and element's borders. Same problem again, I could not find any setting to remove the padding)

Can anyone help me with this?

You can download the Power BI workbook from here as well, if needed: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wzMqe7VsO7_xZxz4K7KeGhyeuymZ4sHf/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible with the native visuals. If you want more control, I suggest something like Deneb.